Why do following blocks "stop" if maximum capacity of a prior block is reached?
I used a queue block to represent an inventory. Therefore I set a maximum capacity within the queue block (250 agents).
When this capacity is reached, the following process blocks stop "working". 
My question is:
Why does the following batch block stop batching agents, just because the queue in front of it has reached its maximum capacity?
I just want the prior blocks to "slow down", when the queue (inventory) is full.
I know I could do some kind of work around with a hold block and so on, but I would like to understand the behavior.
The batch block is setup like this:
￼
The hold block is setup like this:

There is a daily event that checks the demand like this:
if (GoodsInventoryR1 >= maxInventory) {
holdR1.block();  // Stop deliveries when inventory is "full"
} else if (GoodsInventoryR1 <= minInventory) {
holdR1.unblock();   // Allow deliveries when inventory is "low"
}

In the select selectOutput block I chose probabilities for now but I want to apply a different logic later on.
But as soon as one of the hold blocks gets blocked, the batch block stops.

The batch block does not stop due to the queue capacity being reached. You likely set it up such that it cannot batch anymore, share how you defined the batch block as well

And share how you setup the Queue block

And the downstream conditional Hold blocks... essentially make sure we can actually help :)

And pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else other SOF users get confused, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Thank you. I edited the post, in order to add screenshots

Most likely you set the hold blocks to be blocked. Remove them or ensure they are always open and you will see it works. (Always try these small trial models to test stuff like this, much faster to find root causes)
